# How object of one class accessing the data member of other class

Tags: python

i have one class and inside that i am accessing the data member like in one python file called abc.py  . below is the sample piece of the class

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self)    
        main.xyx=10
```

now i am accessing the xyz variable with the use of main which is declared as a object in anothe class in another file. below is the sample of class of other file

```
class cba:
    def __init__(self)
        __builtin__.main = self
```

my doubt is why and how we are using xyz with main(which is not the object of class abc but a an object of class cba)

Comment: If it was `__builtins__` rather than `__builtin__`, that would be a likely explanation. Maybe there was a `__builtin__ = __builtins__` earlier?

Comment: Could you clarify your situation? For instance, is your code located in different ``.py`` files? What do you want to do with ``main`` in class ``abc``? Is ``xyz`` initialized in ``cba``? What exactly is bothering you?
Btw, you forgot the columns after ``__init__(self)``

Comment: I have modified the question according the scenario, So if you understand the problem will you please give solution .. i am completely stucked